# removing rows from dataframes in a list using R

Tags: r, list

I have several files in one folder that I read into R as a list.  Each element in the list is a data frame and I need to remove a random consecutive 6000 rows form each data frame.  I can unlist the data frames and pull out the rows but ideally I would like to keep it in the list and just go through each element of the list and remove the rows I need.  I thought a for loop or apply function would work but the individual elements don't seem t be recognized as data frames when they're in the list.

Here is what I have so far

```
files  <- list.files('file location')
fs <- lapply(files, read.table, sep=',',skip=3,header=TRUE)

##separates the list into individual data frames
for (i in seq(fs))
  assign(paste("df", i, sep = ""), fs[[i]])

##selects a random 6000 rows to remove from a dataframe
n <- nrow(df1)
samp <- sample(1:(n-6000),1)
rmvd <- df1[-seq(from = samp, to =samp+5999),]
```

I would either like to apply the last part to each dataframe individually and put those back into a list or be able to apply it to the list.  I want it in a list in the end because it will be easier to write each dataframe to its own csv file.

Comment: If you stick with `fs` instead of using your `assign` loop, you can do `lapply(fs, function(x) x[-(sample(nrow(x)-6000,1)+0:5999), ])` or similar. If `n` is ever under 6000, you're in trouble, of course.

Comment: without a bit of code to produce some example files, it is hard to answer your question. But you might look at the foreach package. Use foreach(df in fs) %do% { } and stick your removing code in the {}. That will return the "removed" dataframes in a list.

Comment: Thanks @Frank! That was exactly what I was going for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you stick with the list of data.frames, `fs`, instead of `assign`ing them, you can do something like

```
lapply(fs, function(x) x[-(sample(nrow(x)-6000,1)+0:5999), ])
```

If `n=nrow(x)` is ever under `6000`, you're in trouble, of course.